# What are the “savings” one makes by choosing a server install over a desktop?

Tags: server, performance, desktop-environments

I’ve been using 18.04 server for several months to host a few services.  I’ve recently started diving into Docker and in many of the guides I encounter they give command line calls that use NetworkManager, which is not installed with server.  This is annoying to the point I’m asking myself why I’m not using Desktop.

I chose the server flavor mostly because I like the geekiness of the command line.  I also figured it is less resource intensive than its Desktop counterpart.  I know I can install Desktop and still use the command line, but what am I “saving” by using Server over Desktop, especially if both versions use the same kernel?

If I’m using the machine as a server, how much is Desktop costing me in terms of resources and performance?

Comment: It honestly depends on the Desktop Environment that you choose to run.  Lubuntu and Xubuntu are both lightweights when it comes to resources compared to some of the others.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available to help you make a choice.

Comment: You can disable desktop greeter from startup, and start it manually when needed. This way you'll have text login and screen